# How to use DENSE_RANK and order by aditional column?

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

I am trying to use dense_rank to get element order for instance:

I have table seq_test with data:

```
create table seq_test (sequence number, role_name varchar2(20));

insert into seq_test values (10, 'B');
insert into seq_test values (20, 'A');

select DENSE_RANK() over (order by role_name) as seq
     , role_name
     , sequence
    from seq_test
    order by sequence
```

after I run the code above, I've got :

```
SEQ   ROLE_NAME SEQUENCE
2     B         10
1     A         20
```

I want to achieve:

```
SEQ   ROLE_NAME SEQUENCE
1     B         10
2     A         20
```

So DENSE_RANK() function use its own order defined in function definition I need to order the SEQ column by sequence column.

Update:

I want to get:

```
seq role_name sequence
1   B         10
2   C         15
2   C         15
3   A         25
3   A         30
```

Comment: If you need `SEQ` ordered by `SEQUENCE`, then why is the dense rank function ordered by `ROLE_NAME`? It should be ordered by `SEQUENCE`. Sorry, but the question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: wouldn't your dense rank be `(order by role_name desc)`? and why dense_rank... row_number() seems like it would work given data  I don't see a reason for dense_rank given sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the conventional ***`ORDER BY`*** clause is performed after the ***`analytic processing`***. So the ***`ORDER BY`*** clause of the SELECT statement will always take precedence over that comes from the order of the rows as they are processed by an *analytic function*.

In your case `ORDER BY sequence` overrides `ORDER BY role_name` which comes from the *analytic function* .

Btw, what you need depending *on the last comment* might be resolved by adding an extra `MIN()` analytic function such as

```sql
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY seq) AS seq, role_name, sequence
  FROM
  (
   SELECT MIN(sequence) OVER (PARTITION BY role_name ) AS seq,
          role_name, sequence
     FROM seq_test
  ) t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b2de749acc7253bc3cbe686a8a67918)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
select DENSE_RANK() over (order by SEQUENCE) as seq
 , role_name
 , sequence
from seq_test;
```

Result:

```
seq role_name sequence
  1 B               10
  2 A               20
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use role_name and get the same "SEQ" for duplicate role_names